# Problems connecting to database on azure sql

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, azure, entity-framework-core

I'm trying do do the update-database on Entity Framework Core, which gives me this error.

```
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Login failed for user 'hxxxxxxxo@hxxxxxxxogmail.onmicrosoft.com'.
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CheckPoolBlockingPeriod(Exception e)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, SqlConnectionOverrides overrides)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open(SqlConnectionOverrides overrides)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerConnection.OpenDbConnection(Boolean errorsExpected)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenInternal(Boolean errorsExpected)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.Open(Boolean errorsExpected)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerDatabaseCreator.<>c__DisplayClass18_0.<Exists>b__0(DateTime giveUp)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ExecutionStrategyExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass12_0`2.<Execute>b__0(DbContext c, TState s)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ExecutionStrategyExtensions.Execute[TState,TResult](IExecutionStrategy strategy, TState state, Func`2 operation, Func`2 verifySucceeded)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ExecutionStrategyExtensions.Execute[TState,TResult](IExecutionStrategy strategy, TState state, Func`2 operation)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerDatabaseCreator.Exists(Boolean retryOnNotExists)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerDatabaseCreator.Exists()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.HistoryRepository.Exists()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.Migrate(String targetMigration)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.UpdateDatabase(String targetMigration, String connectionString, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabaseImpl(String targetMigration, String connectionString, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabase.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
ClientConnectionId:429fba14-5656-4560-9cb8-efb35ab0dc34
Error Number:18456,State:1,Class:14
Login failed for user 'hxxxxxxxo@hxxxxxxxogmail.onmicrosoft.com'.
```

I can connect with SSMS with this password and connect to the database, I have other API and I can connect to it, I don't know what happens.

```
services.AddDbContext<AAAADbContext>(options => 
  options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnectionString")));
```

Connection String

```
"DefaultConnectionString": "Server=tcp:xxxx-xxxxxxxx.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=xxxxxxxxxxxDb;Persist Security Info=False;User ID= ;Password= ;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Authentication=Active Directory Password"
```

Comment: I hope that isn't your *real* onmicrosoft account address you've exposed there.

Comment: I believe this is typically a wrong username and password combination error. So either the username is incorrect, or the password is incorrect (or both ;)

Comment: @nikneem or the user is not correctly created in the azure database, hard to tell/guess

Comment: When you connect in SSMS do you get a browser popup to authenticate?  ActiveDirectoryPassword only works for accounts without 2FA or which otherwise don't require a federated authentication redirect.

Answer (score 0):

More information on [MSSQLSERVER_18456](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/mssqlserver-18456-database-engine-error?):

> When a connection attempt is rejected because of an authentication failure that involves a bad password or user name, a message similar to the following is returned to the client: "Login failed for user '<user_name>'. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 18456)".

More information on State 1:

> Error information is not available. This state usually means you do not have permission to receive the error details. Contact your SQL Server administrator for more information.

It seems like this all boils down to either a bad username/password, or misconfiguration of the user/database.

**EDIT:**

Have you looked at using a Managed Identity to connect to your database?

> App Service provides a highly scalable, self-patching web hosting service in Azure. It also provides a managed identity for your app, which is a turn-key solution for securing access to [Azure SQL Database](/azure/sql-database/) and other Azure services. Managed identities in App Service make your app more secure by eliminating secrets from your app, such as credentials in the connection strings. In this tutorial, you will add managed identity to the sample web app you built in one of the following tutorials:
>
> - Tutorial: Build an ASP.NET app in Azure with Azure SQL Database
> - Tutorial: Build an ASP.NET Core and Azure SQL Database app in Azure App Service

Source: [Tutorial: Secure Azure SQL Database connection from App Service using a managed identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-connect-msi)

Comment: I tried other users with other passwords, delete database, recreate the database. I'm 2 days around this. I ran out of ideas

Comment: It might help to add this type of information to your question instead of only stating you get an error.